# SQL DATETIME in create table causes parsing error

Tags: mysql, sql, database, node.js, express

When attempting to run this query in Node.JS/Express using MySQL, I get an error.

Without the line "created DATETIME,\n" the code works perfectly. When including that line, or any variation of it (such as trying to attempt to put a default date of the current time), it also says the exact same error.

"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the ... (redacted) ... for the right syntax to use  near '' at line 4"

```
var create_elements = 
    "CREATE TABLE elements(\n" +
    "id          INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,\n" +
    "googleID    VARCHAR(60),\n"  +
    "created     DATETIME,\n"
    "title       VARCHAR(300),\n" +
    "body        TEXT,\n"         +
    "type        ENUM('blog', 'issue'),\n" +
    "PRIMARY KEY (id)\n"          +
    ");";
```

Comment: You're missing a `+` after `"created     DATETIME,\n"`, is that a typo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no plus sign after your new string snippet containing the DATETIME line, so the resulting string does not contain the remaining elements or closing parenthesis and is syntactically invalid.